# I just started the most basic Marmalade c++ application with IwNUI and it is giving errors. What does this message mean?

Tags: c++, marmalade

This error message comes from the tutorial for setting up a native ui mobile application with marmalade + c++.

error message:

```
Message: Failed to open file iwui_style/iwui_style.group
```

Here is the main file:

```
#include "IwNUI.h"

using namespace IwNUI;

int main()
{
    CAppPtr app = CreateApp();
    CWindowPtr window = CreateWindow();

    app->AddWindow(window);

    CViewPtr view = CreateView("canvas");

    CButtonPtr button1 = CreateButton(CAttributes()
        .Set("name",    "Button1")
        .Set("caption", "Hello World!")
        .Set("x1",      "10")
        .Set("y1",      "10"));

    view->AddChild(button1);

    window->SetChild(view);

    app->ShowWindow(window);

    app->Run();

    return 0;
}
```

and the mkb file:

```
files
{
    (source)
    app.cpp
}

subprojects
{
    s3e
    IwNUI
}

defines
{
    IW_USE_LEGACY_MODULES
}
```

Any help would be great.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The IwNUI module uses IwUI module as a backup. As a hack you can just copy the data folder of the IwNUI basic example project to your project. The data folder will have the resources group file which you've included in your project.